# Busy Barbershop Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, poisson-distribution

So the question says: A barbershop has two barbers: an experienced owner and an apprentice. The owner cuts hair at the rate of 4 customers/hour, while the apprentice can only do 2 customers/hour. The owner and the apprentice work simultaneously, however any new customer will always go rst to the owner, if the latter is available. The barbershop has waiting room for only 1 customer (in case both barbers are busy), any additional customers are turned away. Suppose customers walk by the barbershop at the rate of 6 customers/hour. Construct a model to find the proportion of time the apprentice is busy cutting hair.

So I am not sure what the question means by "construct a model". Does it mean that I should construct a markov chain. If so, what should I use it to find the proportion time of the apprentice is busy chutting hair?

Comment: Not sure if your model is a M/M/2 queuing model with heterogeneous server.